# Finding solutions of equation without using inequalities.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem is as follows:

> Find the unique ordered triple of positive integers $(a,b,c)$ with
>   $a\leq b\leq c$ such that
>
> $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{abc}=\frac{25}{84}$$

The problem is easy to solve by first bounding $a$, then bounding $b$ and finally $c$. This is the solution I was given:

It's obvious that $a\geq 4$, otherwise $\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{abc}$ would have to be negative, which we don't want. We also have

$$\frac{25}{84}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{abc}\leq \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{a^3}=\frac{1+a+a^2}{a^3}$$

$$\frac{25}{84}\leq \frac{1+a+a^2}{a^3}$$

so $a\leq 4$ in order to satisfy the inequality, hence $a=4$. We can proceed in a similar manner to solve the rest of the problem.

Yes, this solution is simple and beautiful, but suppose I just want to solve this problem using a rigorous number-theoretic method (e.g. without inequalities). How would I go about doing this?

*EDIT* By the way, this problem was from part C of the 2013 COMC.

Comment: The inequalities are a rigorous method - they constrain the search space. Your constraints $a\le b\le c$ are inequalities, so it is hard to dispense with inequalities.

Comment: I know a solution with inequalities. I'm just trying to find one that doesn't use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write your equation in the form
$c=\frac{84}{25ab-84b-84}$

Comment: And how do we solve this in integers ?

Comment: use that $84=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 7$

Comment: How would I continue? It seems like more of a mess than the original.

Comment: but $25ab-84b-84$ must be one of the numbers $1\cdot 2^2\cdot 3 \cdot 7$